# Compiled SASS from django-pipeline not found by staticfiles even though it's present

Tags: django, sass, django-staticfiles, django-pipeline

I've configured `django-pipeline` as follows:

```
PIPELINE = {
    'PIPELINE_ENABLED': True,
    'COMPILERS': (
        'pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler',
    ),
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'common': {
            'source_filenames': (
                'sass/common/styles.scss',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'css/common/styles.css',
        }
    }
}
```

I ran `collectstatic` and started the server in debug mode to see if everything's set up properly. I can access all my images and scripts, but not the compiled CSS file. My static settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.environ.get('DJANGO_STATIC_ROOT', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)
```

Some more observations:

- I added a breakpoint to `django.views.static.serve` and I noticed that it would trigger for http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/sass/, but not for http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/common/styles.css. However, the compiled CSS file is present in `_static/css/common/` (as `styles.css` and `styles.cba140b2c4b2.css`).
- If I copy the contents of `_static/css/` into the originating app's `static` folder, the CSS renders normally.
- Another possible symptom is that my templates aren't outputting versioned static file paths.

How can I make `staticfiles` find the compiled CSS file?

Comment: Try removing `PIPELINE_ENABLED` and see if it works.